# How to perform self convolution (convolution with itself) in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch

PyTorch offers a functional 2D convolution operation `torch.nn.functional.conv2d` which may take an input and a weight parameter (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#conv2d).

I want to perform a self convolution, meaning that given a tensor X. I want to calculate:

```
conv2d(X, X)
```

However the shape of the filter is expected to be of the form `[out_ch, in_channel/groups, kernel_size, kernel_size]`.

Let's say `X` is of the form `[32, 3, 16, 16,]` I have tried to permute X to try to match the expected form of the weight parameter, such as:

```
W = X.permute(1, 0, 2, 3) # 3, 32, 16, 16 
conv2d(X, W)
```

But that does not work since `32 != in_channel/groups == 3 / 1 == 3`

The complete operation would essentially look like this (to see the dimensions requirements):

```
X + conv2d(X, X)
```

Is it possible to do this with PyTorch?

Other packages such as SciPy offers a `convolve2d` operation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.convolve2d.html) but that only supports 2D arrays, and appears to do what I'm trying to do above, but without support for batches and channels.

Comment: Do you want channels to be processed independently, what is result shape you expect?

Comment: @AlexeyBirukov I would expect the shape to be unchanged. The channels can be processed together.

Comment: How are you planning to keep the shape unchanged if you are convolving over the full tensor shape though? To me it sounds like you want to perform a point-wise multiplication, otherwise you'd get a shape that is at least padded, or otherwise has its dimensions changed.

Comment: @dennlinger I'm not sure. I'm attempting to implement a particular piece in a network, where (circular) convolution with the variable itself is performed (the variable has been transformed a certain way before the convolution). Size there is no padding needed (convolution with itself) I think this means it ends up being simply the same as a standard linear convolution with itself.

To make the dimensions workout it seems like the dimensions of the result would have to remain unchanged.

Comment: Again, if you're doing a convolution, your dimensions by definition of a convolution cannot be the same for input and output, even (or especially) if your dimensions of the filter and tensor match. Please provide a [mcve] of your expected input, and output.

Comment: @dennislinger Please see the updated question. Essentially the following should hold with valid dimensions: X + conv2d(X, X)

Comment: @Alexander Since you want to apply a different filter on each channel of each batch you will not easily be able to take advantage of the batching behavior of conv2d. The naive approach would be to take one channel from one batch element at a time and perform self convolution (one channel in and one channel out). So the input and filter would be the same and would be size (1,1,16,16). Then construct your result tensor using all the conv results. This would be quite slow though. I'm trying to think of how this could be sped up.